# ssl keystore generated from certbot (standalone) does not work with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I am trying to add a ssl certificate generated from certbot, converted into pkcs12 format into my spring-boot application.

Those are the steps I made to make the certificate:

```
certbot certonly -a standalone -d api.example.com
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out pkcs.p12 -name tomcat -passout pass:aaaaaa
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass aaaaaa -destkeypass aaaaaa -destkeystore .keystore -srckeystore pkcs.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass aaaaaa -alias tomcat
```

[source](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/SSL+certificates+with+cerbot+-+including+wildcard+SSL+certificates)

The content of application.yml :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/api?useSSL=false
    username: spring
    password: w7wqD6hd78HfYHLP
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
server:
  port: 12345
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: tomcat
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-password: aaaaaa
    key-store: /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.ovh/pkcs.p12
```

This is the most nested error I obtain :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1170) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:365) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

The pkcs12 has been created with the fullchain and the key, so there should be no problem in the resulting p12 certificate. They are various answers on the wonderful internet that directed me in the same direction for the steps to make the certificate.

I would like to know if anyone has a solution for this, to simply use ssl as intended. If the answer is obvious, I am sorry, I am not savvy enough on java applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `key-store-password` property as follows:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-password: aaaaaa
```